# Is there a way to show that $d(n)$, which counts the number of divisors of $n$ is non-increasing?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, divisor-counting-function

Is there a way to show that $d(n)$, which counts the number of divisors of $n$ is non-increasing?

I'm trying to use the Cauchy condensation test to show that $\sum_{n\ge{2}}\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2n}$ is divergent. In order to do this, I have to show that $\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2n}$ is non increasing,

If I can show that $d(n)$ is non-increasing then I am done, but I don't know where to start with this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-increasing"? Just the negation of increasing? Or $n<m \Rightarrow d(n)\geqslant d(m)$ ? These two things are different: the former is true whereas the latter is false.

Comment: Just the negation of increasing.

Comment: Showing that $\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2n}$ is non-increasing is _vastly_ different from showing that $d(n)$ is non-increasing.  The latter isn't so, but that has no bearing on the former.

Comment: would you mind flagging this for deletion?

Comment: I guess you should ask "convergence or divergence" of the series $\sum \frac{d(n)}{n\log^2 n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by 'non-increasing', you mean 'monotonically decreasing'. (You said in the comment that you wanted to apply Cauchy condensation test and Wikipedia's [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) article uses such term)

Well, the problem is that $\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2 n}$ is not monotonically decreasing since $$\frac{d(p)}{p\log^2p}=\frac{2}{p\log^2p}<\frac{3}{(p+1)\log^2(p+1)}\le\frac{d(p+1)}{(p+1)\log^2(p+1)}$$ for all sufficiently large prime $p$. So you cannot use that test.

The divergence can be shown by estimating the sum assymptotically.
Let $$C(x):=\sum_{k\le x}c_n$$
Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=a}^{b}c_nf(n)&=\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n)(C(n)-C(n-1))\\
&=\sum_{n=a}^{b-1}C(n)(f(n)-f(n+1))+f(b)C(b)-f(a)C(a-1)\\
&=f(b)C(b)-f(a)C(a-1)-\sum_{n=a}^{b-1}C(n)\int_n^{n+1}f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=f(b)C(b)-f(a)C(a-1)-\sum_{n=a}^{b-1}\int_n^{n+1}f'(x)C(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=f(b)C(b)-f(a)C(a-1)-\int_a^bf'(x)C(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
Now put $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x\log^2x}, c_n=d(n)$$
Then we have
$$\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2n}=\frac{1}{m\log^2m}\sum_{n\le m} d(n)-\frac{1}{2\log^22}+\int_2^m\frac{2+\log x}{x^2\log^3x}\sum_{n\le x}d(n)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
There is an estimation on the sum of number divisors using the hyperbola method.(see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/dirichlets-divisor-problem)) That is,$$\sum_{n\le x}d(n)=x\log x+(2\gamma-1)x+O(\sqrt{x})$$
Now plugging this on the above sum, we get$$\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2n}=\log\log m+O(1)$$ which is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

How could $d(n)$ be non-increasing? $3$ has $2$ divisors, $4$ has $3$ divisors, meaning that $$d(3)=2\\
d(4)=3\\
d(5)=2$$
meaning $d$ is neither non-decreasing nor non-increasing.

Comment: I understand, but I am trying to use the Cauchy condensation test in showing that $\sum_{n\ge{2}}\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2n}$ is divergent, and to do so I must show that $\frac{d(n)}{n\log^2n}$ is non increasing. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I mean that the sequence is non-increasing. But I think you are right. It cannot be increasing.