# How many distinct values of floor(N/i) exists for i=1 to N.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, periodic-functions

Say we have a function $F(i)=\text{floor}(N/i)$.

Then how many distinct values of $F(i)$ will exist for all $0 \leq i \leq N$

e.g. We have $N=25$ then.

$F(1)=25$

$F(2)=12$

$F(3)=8$

$F(4)=6$

$F(5)=5$

...

...

...

$F(24)=1$

$F(25)=1$

So total distinct values of $F(i)$ are $(N=25)$ :- $25, 12, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1$

total distinct values are $9$: $(2 \times 5-1)$

Can anyone please help in that total number of distinct values are $O(\sqrt{N})$?

Comment: What if $N$ isn't a square?  Then the number of distinct values can't be $2\sqrt N-1$, because that isn't a whole number.

Comment: They exist in O(sqrt N)

Comment: Look here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/dirichlets-divisor-problem

Comment: Are you trying to say that the number of distinct values is $O(\sqrt N)$?  Or that it is bounded by $2\sqrt N-1$?

Comment: Can you please help me in coming up with some simpler proof.

Comment: Upper bound is **sqrt N**

Comment: @martycohen is there any other simple intutive proof?

Comment: Sorry. My advice is to look at the various proofs in different number theory books and articles.

Comment: I dont have one right now.

Comment: I have searched all over the internet but there isn't any thing relevant that could help me in reaching the proof.......i don't want a formal proof even an intutive proof will work

Comment: @Donkey_2009 No idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $k \leqslant \sqrt{N}$, then $\lfloor N/\lfloor N/k\rfloor\rfloor = k$, since, letting $m = \lfloor N/k\rfloor$, we have $$mk\leqslant N < (m+1)k = mk + k \leqslant mk + m = m(k+1),$$ so that gives you $\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor$ values. And the values of $\lfloor N/k\rfloor$ for $k \leqslant \lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor$ are all different, since

$$\frac{N}{k-1} - \frac{N}{k} = \frac{N}{k(k-1)} > 1$$

for $1 < k \leqslant \lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor$.

So you have either $2\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor$ or $2\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor - 1$ distinct values, depending on whether

$$N \geqslant \lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor(\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor+1)$$

or not.

Comment: Thank You very much Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel! I am sorry I may sound dumb, but how does proving $mk < m(k+1)$ prove that $\lfloor N/\lfloor N/k\rfloor\rfloor = k$?

Comment: @nitrogen The crucial part is the relation to $N$. We have $mk \leqslant N < m(k+1)$. Dividing by $m$ yields $k \leqslant N/m < k+1$, and that means $k = \lfloor N/m\rfloor$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more concept I need to understand, to prove all $\lfloor N/k\rfloor$ are distinct for $1 \lt k \leqslant \lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor$, it is needed to prove that $\lfloor\frac{N}{k-1}\rfloor - \lfloor \frac{N}{k} \rfloor > 0$, but I don't know why you removed the floor function and computed the difference. Why does that work?

Comment: Also, why should the difference be > 1, does not a difference of at least 1 ensure all consecutive floor values are different?

Comment: @nitrogen Suppose $x \leqslant y$. If $\lfloor x\rfloor = \lfloor y\rfloor = n$, then we have $n \leqslant x < n+1$ and $n \leqslant y < n+1$, hence $y-x < (n+1) - n = 1$. So if the difference between two real numbers is at least $1$ (yes, a difference of exactly $1$ is also sufficient), the two numbers have different floors. Since it's easier to compute with $\frac{N}{k}$ and $\frac{N}{k-1}$ than with $\bigl\lfloor\frac{N}{k}\bigr\rfloor$ and $\bigl\lfloor \frac{N}{k-1}\bigr\rfloor$, when that suffices to show the desired thing, one often drops the floors.

Comment: Daniel, can you recommend some topics that help me understand such basic things, I don't know what to look for as I am not a maths student.

Comment: @nitrogen Sorry, I don't know what to recommend. Except of course practice. And more practice. Apart from that, maybe an introduction to Number Theory (there are lots of good books with approximately that title).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31905/discussion-between-nitrogen-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 3):

Let $k = \left\lfloor{\frac{N}{i}}\right\rfloor$. Take two cases -

1. $k \le \sqrt{N}$: Clearly there are $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ possible values for $k$ in this case
2. $k > \sqrt{N}$: In this case $i \le \sqrt{N}$. Since there are $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ possible values for $i$, there are $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ values for $k$ as well.

$\implies$ the maximum distinct values of $k$ is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$

Answer (score 0):

Get the ceil() value of the positive root of the equation t^2 + t - (N + 1) = 0.
Let's say the required root be r, then compare (r^2 - 1) with N if (r^2 - 1 >= N)
the answer will be 2 * ( r - 1) else the answer will be 2 * (r - 1) + 1.
Here is cpp psuedo code :

```
    int n; // get n
    int r = ceil((sqrt(5 + 4 * n) - 1.00) / 2.00);
    if(r * r - 1 >= n)
        return 2 * (r - 1);
    else
        return 2 * (r - 1) + 1;
```